# Android x86 Audio crashes when volume is increased

Tags: android, audio, alsa

I have compiled the Android x86 4.4 RC1 and installed it on my intel atom based desktop computer.

It Uses the HDA Intel sound driver by default and plays fine when volume is up to 85%.

but when volume is increased to 100 % it suddenly turns off the audio and the correcponding logcat events are logged.

[image: ScreenShot Of Logcat when Sound turns Off]

After I set the following it works because the maximum output is restricted by the alsa mixer

`alsa_amixer sset Master 75
 alsa_amixer sset Front 73
 alsa_amixer sset Capture 75`

The sound output is considerably lowered.
Can someone recommend a solution based on the logcat output provided?.

on request I can attach the output of

> alsa_amixer -c 0

Ty in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

In your init.sh add this line to the end of the alsa_amixer stuff:

`alsa_amixer set PCM 100 unmute`

Add it in your audio.

Comment: sorry for the late reply . . .but yea I've tried this as suggested from some other SO question  . . but this was meant for some people who had no audio output . . i have output but its crashing when i increase the volume beyond 90%. Also PCM is not part of my scontrols or my controls list.